# XGBoost image classification Bad Allocation error

Tags: python, xgboost, image-classification

So I am using Xgboost for an image classification problem but I am getting a Bad Allocation error when running model.fit and passing the train data. I think that the problem must be the data but its in a 2d array as supported by XGBoost also when the data had been passed through a VGG16 Feature Extractor it worked with no problem. Any possible solutions please?

```
x = np.array(allImages)<br>
y = np.array(allLabels)<br>
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.2,random_state=123)<br>
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()<br>
le.fit(y_train)<br>
y_train_encoded = le.transform(y_train)<br>
del y_train<br>
le.fit(y_test)<br>
y_test_encoded = le.transform(y_test)<br>
x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0],-1)<br>
model = xgb.XGBClassifier(use_label_encoder=False,objective='multi:softprob', 
                    num_class= 10)<br>
model.fit(x_train,y_train_encoded)<br>

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
XGBoostError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-d0749b6882f3> in <module>
      5 model = xgb.XGBClassifier(use_label_encoder=False,objective='multi:softprob', 
      6                       num_class= 10)
----> 7 model.fit(x_train,y_train_encoded)
      8 #For the kFold
      9 le.fit(y)

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\xgboost\core.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
    420         for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args):
    421             kwargs[k] = arg
--> 422         return f(**kwargs)
    423 
    424     return inner_f

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\xgboost\sklearn.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, base_margin, eval_set, eval_metric, early_stopping_rounds, verbose, xgb_model, sample_weight_eval_set, feature_weights, callbacks)
    901         self.n_features_in_ = self._features_count
    902 
--> 903         train_dmatrix, evals = self._wrap_evaluation_matrices(
    904             X, y, group=None, sample_weight=sample_weight, base_margin=base_margin,
    905             feature_weights=feature_weights,

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\xgboost\sklearn.py in _wrap_evaluation_matrices(self, X, y, group, sample_weight, base_margin, feature_weights, eval_set, sample_weight_eval_set, eval_group, label_transform)
    263 
    264         y = label_transform(y)
--> 265         train_dmatrix = DMatrix(data=X, label=y, weight=sample_weight,
    266                                 base_margin=base_margin,
    267                                 missing=self.missing, nthread=self.n_jobs)

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\xgboost\core.py in __init__(self, data, label, weight, base_margin, missing, silent, feature_names, feature_types, nthread, enable_categorical)
    498 
    499         from .data import dispatch_data_backend
--> 500         handle, feature_names, feature_types = dispatch_data_backend(
    501             data, missing=self.missing,
    502             threads=self.nthread,

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\xgboost\data.py in dispatch_data_backend(data, missing, threads, feature_names, feature_types, enable_categorical)
    528         return _from_scipy_csr(data.tocsr(), missing, feature_names, feature_types)
    529     if _is_numpy_array(data):
--> 530         return _from_numpy_array(data, missing, threads, feature_names,
    531                                  feature_types)
    532     if _is_uri(data):

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\xgboost\data.py in _from_numpy_array(data, missing, nthread, feature_names, feature_types)
    145     flatten = _transform_np_array(data)
    146     handle = ctypes.c_void_p()
--> 147     _check_call(_LIB.XGDMatrixCreateFromMat_omp(
    148         flatten.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float)),
    149         c_bst_ulong(data.shape[0]),

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\xgboost\core.py in _check_call(ret)
    187     """
    188     if ret != 0:
--> 189         raise XGBoostError(py_str(_LIB.XGBGetLastError()))
    190 
    191 

XGBoostError: bad allocation
```

Comment: Have you found out any solution for this problem?